# Onsubmit function not working with if else condition in jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation

```
<form name="add_employee_frm" id="add_employee_frm" method="post" onsubmit="return validator();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select name='org_id'>
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">XYZ</option>
    </select>
    //other inputs fields
</form>
```

**Above is my html form with onsubmit function. My condition is if value is not `1` then only `validator` function should work.if value is `1` then validator function should not work.for this i applied one script but every time it goes in else condtion.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validator() 
        {   
          var x = document.forms["add_employee_frm"]["employee_number"].value;
            if (x == "") 
            {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }                       
        }
</script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
    var s = document.getElementsByName('org_id')[0];
    s.addEventListener("change", changeOrg);
    function changeOrg()
    {   
        var frmvalidator = "";
        var value = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(value);
        if(value === 1)
            {   
                return false;

            }           
        else if(value !== 1)
            {
                var frmvalidator = new Validator(); 

            }
    }
changeOrg();        
}); 
</script>
```

`chaneOrg` function is used to get org_id onchange dropdown list.then `validator` function for validate form.

Comment: You don't have an element with name employee_number.

Comment: Incomplete html code. where is the "employee_number" field?

Comment: i dont pur here bro

Comment: I think `s.options[s.selectedIndex].value` returns a string '1' which you compare with a integer `if(value === 1)`

Comment: @sTx That is not a concern with JavaScript. A simple test `1 == "1"` will confirm this.

Comment: @AndyG as far as I know `'1' === 1` returns false

Comment: @sTx My apologies. I missed the extra equals. I must be tired ;)

Comment: also I don't understand this code: `var frmvalidator = new Validator(); ` what is `Validator()` a class?

Comment: @sTx right. its not working for me. i just found with console that it wont work. i was trying to call my `Validator()` function inside else condition.

Comment: you call it like this `validator()` - that's all

Comment: `var frmvalidator = Validator();` but still its not working for me.

Comment: your function name is `validator` not `Validator`, the correct code is :`var frmvalidator = validator()`  but why you do that instantiation?

Comment: @sTx ya i solve that typo. but still not overcome my problem.

Comment: `if(value != 1)    {validator();//here you call the function, that's it       }` also be aware of `!=` and not `!==`

Comment: or use `if(value !== '1')` I still think your returned value is a string not an integer